# Stretch Bitmap without anti-aliasing

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, stretching

I found this example and used it [How do you resize a Bitmap under .NET CF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082884/how-do-you-resize-a-bitmap-under-net-cf-2-0/1082890#1082890)

However my image looks horrible because of anti aliasing. It no longer looks pixelated as it should. How do i disable anti aliasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the interpolation mode to nearest neighbor:

```
g.InterPolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
```