# How to stretch a Bitmap to fill a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

I need to stretch various sized bitmaps to fill a PictureBox.
`PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage` sort of does what I need but can't think of a way to properly add text or lines to the image using this method. The image below is a 5x5 pixel Bitmap stretched to a 380x150 PictureBox.

[image: using pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage]

```
pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox.Image = bmp;
```

I tried adapting [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082884/how-do-you-resize-a-bitmap-under-net-cf-2-0/1082890#1082890) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096553/stretch-bitmap-without-anti-aliasing/1096627#1096627) this way

```
using (var bmp2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height))
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2))
{
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp2.Size));
    pictureBox.Image = bmp2;
}
```

but get this

[image: using g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp2.Size))]

What am I missing?

Comment: You haven't disposed the image at last.After g.drawImage() try using bmp.dispose();

Comment: Dispose pictureBox.Image, not bmp2.

Comment: Why bother with Dispose? Isn't that the job of the GC?

Comment: @JackN: no. Finalizers are the responsibility of the GC. Dispose is the responsibility of the encompassing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you're throwing away the bitmap (`bmp2`) you'd like to see in your picture box! The `using` block from [the example you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082884/how-do-you-resize-a-bitmap-under-net-cf-2-0/1082890#1082890) is used because the code no longer needs the `Bitmap` object after the code returns. In your example you need the Bitmap to hang around, hence no `using`-block on the `bmp2` variable.

The following should work:

```
using (bmp)
{
    var bmp2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp2.Size));
        pictureBox.Image = bmp2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Meta-comment: you should probably protect exception paths in this code from leaking `bmp2`.

Answer (score 3):

The red X on white background happens when you have an exception in a paint method.

Your error is that you are trying to assign a disposed bitmap as the image source of your picturebox. The use of "using" keyword will dispose the bitmap you are using in the picturebox!

So your exception, i know, will be ObjectDisposedException :)

You should create the bitmap once and keep it until it is not needed anymore.

```
void ReplaceResizedPictureBoxImage(Bitmap bmp)
{
    var oldBitmap = pictureBox.Image;

    var bmp2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp2.Size));
        pictureBox.Image = bmp2;
    }

    if (oldBitmap != null)
        oldBitmap.Dispose();
}
```

This function will allow you to replace the old bitmap disposing the previous one, if you need to do that to release resources.